# How to install Ubuntu via network?

Tags: boot, networking, server

We have 10 computers connected via a switch. I installed Ubuntu server on 1 PC in LAN.

Now I want to install Ubuntu desktop. for that I have created an .ISO image with a bunch of software installed on it) so I want to install on rest of  other 9 PC's. How can I install Ubuntu desktop into them via network (Ubuntu server).

PS: My college had taught only **WDS**.
I want to know how it can be done on Ubuntu.

Comment: You want a PXE server right.  Go here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this yet but i found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot), don't know if this can help you. let me know it goes.

Comment: theres also network installer here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads